# JDBC connection to MSSQL server using azure active directory

Tags: sql-server, scala, jdbc, databricks

I know you can connect to sever using jdbc connection with SQL authentication or windows authentication but can I use azure active directory to do it?

Code for jdbc with windows authentication

```
val jdbcHostname = "hostname"
val jdbcPort = 1433
val jdbcDatabase = "database_name"
val jdbcUrl ="jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort};database=${jdbcDatabase};integratedSecurity=true"
val username="windows_username"
val password="windows_password"
val driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
#read as spark df
val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", jdbcUrl)
  .option("dbtable", table)
  .option("user", username)
  .option("password", password)
  .option("driver", driver)
  .load()
```

Comment: Relevant? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Connection properties to support Azure Active Directory authentication in the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server.

The connection string properties can be specified in various ways:

- As name=value properties in the connection URL when you connect by
  using the DriverManager class. For connection string syntax, see
  Building the connection URL.
- As name=value properties in the Properties parameter of the Connect
  method in the DriverManager class

Here is the Microsoft Document : Connecting using Azure Active Directory authentication | [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15)  & The following table lists all the currently available connection string properties for the JDBC driver | [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-ver15#properties).